# Nonhomogenous Linear System question

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to follow along with this example in the book, but I'm lost at how they got from 1 step to the next. 
[image]

I see how it reduces after taking out the E term but I can't figure out how the inverse of the 2x2 equation times "a" come out of there.

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 30 minutes but I keep getting stuck.

EDIT: Ah, it was the identity matrix that was escaping me, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

After cancelling the $e^{2t}$ factor but before rearranging anything, you have

$2{a} = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix} a + \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Now remember that $2a$ is actually 2 times the identity matrix times a,

$2a = 2\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} a = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} a$

so you really have the equation

$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} a = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix} a + \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

or

$\Big(\,\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\,\Big)\,a = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

or

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}\,a = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Next you need to find the inverse of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}$ and that's easy to find. It equals

$\begin{bmatrix}-1/3&-2/3\\-2/3&-1/3\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus,

$a = \begin{bmatrix}-1/3&-2/3\\-2/3&-1/3\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1/3\\-2/3\end{bmatrix}$.

**Edit:** In case your difficulty is with finding the inverse, just solve this simple system

$\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\u&v\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ for $(x,y,u,v)$.